# Hibernate pass column name dynamically to the query

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to pass a column name dynamically to the query in hibernate but I have not been able to do so. Can you shed light on how to do this? I have tried `Restrictions` like the following:

```
getCurrentSession()
.createCriteria(Result.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq(option.column_name, "first_test")).list();
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
"test_name,le" of: com..model.Result
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: When you say pass a "column name" dynamically, do you mean "property name"? Or do you really mean that you are trying to dynamically choose how a given property of the object is mapped to a column in the database?

Comment: I meant property name. For example I have a table with following columns: column1, column2. These are displayed as select options in the UI and I want to use them to create query like "select * from table where column1=some value". If column2 is selected from the dropdown the query will be "select * from table where column2=some value"

Comment: I think the answer, then, is just that you fed it a string that isn't a property name.  It is hard to image that "test_name,le" is the name of one of your properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It seems like your entity `Result` doesn't have property
  `test_name,le`

Please make sure you pass correct field name, for example:

```
@Entity
class Employee{
   ..
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   ..
}
```

If user selected `firstName` you just need to pass the name of the field as `String`:

```
String fieldName = "firstName";
getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Employee.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq(fieldName, "John")).list();
```

Comment: When I do following I do get results as expected "return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(TestResult.class).add(Restrictions.eq("test_name", "first_test")).list();" But when I do "return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(TestResult.class).add(Restrictions.eq(option.getName(), "first_test")).list();" I get the error as above. Do I need to map the strings to the property somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure that `option.‌​getName()` returns correct field name?

Comment: you are correct. the getoption was returning incorrect response because I had two options with same name which resulted in the conflict.